# Twitter Search with API 1.1

Tags: api, search, authentication, twitter

I was doing an application search tweets using the API 1.0 and was working, but it stopped working when disabled version 1.0 forcing the use of 1.1.

The version 1.1 requests to use authentication. Already got the consumer key and secret key, but I don't know how put this in my code.

Currently my code looks like:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&result_type=mixed&count=4&callback=?", function (data) {
        ctResults = data.results.length;
        $("#ctResults").val("" + ctResults);

        for (var i = 0; i < qtResultados; i++) {
            var result = data.results[i]
            $("#content").append(result.text + "<br>");
        }
    })
```

This way when run gives error for lack of authentication.